# How can I block a site in Windows 7 or 10, allowing it to only be accessible through a VPN?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, vpn, blocking

I want to block a website, locally, and if I want to visit that site, I must use a VPN. How to do that?

In case you are puzzled by my intention, I want to make certain websites only accessible when I'm using a VPN. If the VPN is turned off, this site is completely blocked, but if I turn it on, the website is accessible.

Using Windows 7 and 10.

Comment: Host your own dns server on your network, when connected to your vpn, you no longer use your vpn on the intranet

Answer (score 2):

Add sites you want to block to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` as

`127.0.0.1 bad.site.org`

and when you use VPN to access restricted website, use SOCKS5 to your VPN over Firefox (Prefrence/tools->Advanced->Network->Settings->Manual proxy configuration), but before you will do that tell Firefox to use remote DNS instead of registered in system by going to `about:config` and change attribute `network.proxy.socks_remote_dns` to `true`

P.S.
Other solutions is to use [privoxy](https://www.privoxy.org/) or [Acrylic DNS](http://mayakron.altervista.org/wikibase/show.php?id=AcrylicHome) - local DNS/proxy server for non VPN connections

Comment: Hello, my VPN doesn't appear to support SOCKS.

Comment: @Matt Cox What VPN solution are you using?

Comment: Hello Alex, I'd rather not disclose that, but I can tell you I'm no rookie when it comes to things like this and the VPN is the kind that comes with an exe client and connects to established, well configured remote servers. So there is no option menu somewhere that will pop up an interface in which I can enable socks support, I am sorry.

Comment: I understand. The only thing that I can suggest - ask support from those who provide you that exe file. Usually it is just a wrappers around SSH or local proxy server that reroute connections to remote proxy

Comment: Your suspicion is well founded Alex, but if that were the case, the whole point of the wrapping is not to expose too many functions to the user isn't it?

Comment: @Matt Cox It hard to say without knowing type of VPN, - PPTP, L2TP/IPsec, OpenVPN, socks...  etc....??? Some wrappers used just to simplify users live. There're a hackers wrappers that could be very complicated that use VPN based on chained zombie computers or via IRC bots, it could be also legitimate solution from work environment that protecting(and simplifying their live) mobile users.

Comment: Actually I suspect it's socks. But back to the question, any other work-around? I don't want to switch VPN, and I want to block the target site.

Comment: I updated my answer, take a look